Keep getting a "Network request failed" error when authenticating Realm users in react native;
I have an auth flow that does not work on the Android emulator, but works perfectly fine on a physical device. I'm authenticating users to my Realm app with the following code;
const LogInScreen = () => {

  const {logInWithJWT, result} = useAuth();
  //const {logInWithAnonymous, result} = useAuth();

  const login = React.useCallback(async () => {
    try {
      var tokens = await SignInAzure();
      logInWithJWT(tokens["id_token"]);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
  });

  return (
    <View>
      <Button title="Sign in to realm" onPress={login} />
    </View>
  );
};

I've tried using anonymous login and email/password login and I get the same error on both, but all these methods work when I use a pixel 5 device to run my app. I know the emulator can access the internet because I can get a token from the AzureAD app, but when I try authenticating in realm, it fails immediately without delay.
edit:
Here's the full error
log_in_with_credentials failed: 0 message: request to https://realm.mongodb.com/api/client/v2.0/app/application-0-xxxxxx/location failed, reason: Network request failed

